# Filtering data where threshold is broken in Python Datafr

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter a list of temperature data, where the temperature breaks the 7 - 10 degree threshold. My goal is to create a filtered dataset of days where the temperature breaks the threshold, but not the data in between. I've attached a sample table; currently I am using high/low filters which work, but they include the data in between rather than a list of the dates where the move outside the threshold occurs.

Is this possible with simple python? Thanks in advance!

| Date | Temperature | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-21 | 9.20 |  |
| 02-Jan-21 | 9.50 |  |
| 03-Jan-21 | 10.10 | UPPER |
| 04-Jan-21 | 11.00 |  |
| 05-Jan-21 | 10.50 |  |
| 06-Jan-21 | 10.20 |  |
| 07-Jan-21 | 9.80 |  |
| 08-Jan-21 | 8.50 |  |
| 09-Jan-21 | 6.20 | LOWER |
| 10-Jan-21 | 9.90 |  |
| 11-Jan-21 | 10.10 | UPPER |
| 12-Jan-21 | 10.21 |  |
| 13-Jan-21 | 11.00 |  |
| 14-Jan-21 | 12.10 |  |
| 15-Jan-21 | 11.34 |  |
| 16-Jan-21 | 9.43 |  |
| 17-Jan-21 | 10.22 | UPPER |
| 18-Jan-21 | 11.00 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rows where a column is in between two values (both inclusive) you can use `between`. For the purpose of demonstration, store this in a temporary column

```py
df['in_range'] = df.Temperature.between(7, 10)
```

to get this (ignoring the `Flag` column for the time being):

```py
>>> df.head(10)
        Date  Temperature  in_range
0  01-Jan-21          9.2      True
1  02-Jan-21          9.5      True
2  03-Jan-21         10.1     False
3  04-Jan-21         11.0     False
4  05-Jan-21         10.5     False
5  06-Jan-21         10.2     False
6  07-Jan-21          9.8      True
7  08-Jan-21          8.5      True
8  09-Jan-21          6.2     False
9  10-Jan-21          9.9      True
```

One option to get only the first one out of a series of consecutive `False` rows, we can select the rows where the previous row is `True`. We can do that using `shift`, which by default shifts the rows down by one, i.e., row 0 becomes 1, row 1 becomes 2 etc.

```py
>>> df.in_range.shift().head()
0      NaN
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: in_range, dtype: object
```

The first row has no preceding row, so it gets filled with `NaN`. In your case, however, we need to fill it with `True`. Storing that in another column:

```py
>>> df['in_range_shift'] = df.in_range.shift(fill_value=True)
>>> df.head(10)
        Date  Temperature  in_range  in_range_shift
0  01-Jan-21          9.2      True            True
1  02-Jan-21          9.5      True            True
2  03-Jan-21         10.1     False            True # <-
3  04-Jan-21         11.0     False           False
4  05-Jan-21         10.5     False           False
5  06-Jan-21         10.2     False           False
6  07-Jan-21          9.8      True           False
7  08-Jan-21          8.5      True            True
8  09-Jan-21          6.2     False            True # <-
9  10-Jan-21          9.9      True           False
```

Notice how we get a `(False, True)` in the last two columns at every value that we want.

So just do:

```py
>>> df[~df.in_range & df.in_range_shift] 
         Date  Temperature  in_range  in_range_shift
2   03-Jan-21        10.10     False            True
8   09-Jan-21         6.20     False            True
10  11-Jan-21        10.10     False            True
16  17-Jan-21        10.22     False            True
```

Which, of course, can be done in a much more concise way with the original `df`:

```py
>>> m = df.Temperature.between(7, 10)
>>> df[~m & m.shift(fill_value=True)]
         Date  Temperature   Flag
2   03-Jan-21        10.10  UPPER
8   09-Jan-21         6.20  LOWER
10  11-Jan-21        10.10  UPPER
16  17-Jan-21        10.22  UPPER
```

Comment: Right, but I only want the days where the threshold is initially broken; not the days outside. In a perfect world, the filter would return a list that only includes the flags I had manually added to the data table.

Comment: @grandpa okay, I got it now – please consider my updated/extended answer.

Comment: This is perfect - thank you so much!